# Page freeze when there are many HTML5 video loaded at once

Tags: video, html5-video, freeze

I have a webpage that uses tooltip to show a video to a user. When the tooltip loads, the video is downloaded and played automatically. The problem is when I pop up too many tooltips, and loads too many videos at the same time. is there anyway to solve this problem?

Comment: No code to close current tooltip (and cancel video) when mouse moves away?

Answer (score 0):

Video is very CPU intensive, and most platforms will have a problem playing multiple videos on a web page simultaneously.

Platforms also generally have optimised video playback capability which leverages the platform HW to reduce CPU and battery load, for example by having video decoding performed in dedicated HW. This is generally designed just for one or at best a small number of simultaneous videos, and subsequent videos will have to do much more work in SW which drives up processing and battery usage.

You may find some browsers handle it better than others, and even some releases of the same browser better than other releases, but either way it will cause you, at best, performance or playback issues even if it does not actually freeze.